# Родительский класс при экспорте is not defined

Tags: javascript

я имею среду node.js с кодом приведенным ниже,
при выполнении кода получаю ошибку: ReferenceError: Y is not defined
подскажите что я делаю не правильно?

```js
~main.js

const X = require('./classes.js');

new X();
------------------------------------------------
~classes.js

module.exports = class X extends Y {
  constructor(){
    super();
   
    this.hiAll();
  }
}

class Y{
  hiAll(){
    alert('hi all!');
  }
}
```

Comment: классы не всплывают, почему сначала объявляете X, а уже потом Y?

Comment: в общем определяйте Y раньше X и все

Comment: Странно, до того как я разделил код на два файла, классы располагались в том же порядке и все работало :/

Answer (score 0):

```
class Y {
    hiAll() {
        console.log('hi all!');
    }
}
class X extends Y {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.hiAll();
    }
}

module.exports = X;
```

или

```
class Y {
    hiAll() {
        console.log('hi all!');
    }
}

module.exports = class X extends Y {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.hiAll();
    }
};
```

Comment: Как то так лучше. Определение класса от которого будет делать extends выше.

Comment: Спасибо всем, это работает для меня. Вопрос можно считать исчерпанным если возможно дать объяснение почему так работает.